# Manifest.json Error Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]':Invalid scheme.

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This has been bugging me and I can't figure out the solution.

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["chrome-extension://_MSG_@@extension_id/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
 ],
```

if i was to replace the "chrome-extensions://.." with a url such as http://google.com/* it will work.

I even tried fallowing the pattern on chrome develoeprs pag along with replacing extension id with the actual id.

I am basically trying to inject the content script into a local page "in the extension folder"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you aren't meant to be able to inject content scripts into other extensions. The docs are wrong, I have reported this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153245) while ago.

Comment: I was hoping to inject it into my own extension, to one of the pages. but Thanks for the heads up :/

Comment: Hm, it just hit me. You have a full control over code of your extension why do you want to inject content script into it? Just being curious.

Comment: in manifest I setup an event page named it background.js and in this file it basicaly redirects you to a a local file auth.html using the  chrome.extension.getURL() and I was looking to sendMessage to the event page but every where I looked it shows examples of the content script feature being used to direct the request to it which I never quite understood but it only showed the code for contentscrpt.js somefile.html and background.js (as the event page) so I assumed it had to be done like this within the manifest

Comment: almost forgot to mention am new to building chrome extensions so I get what ever I can from any website including the developers guide but as you know some of the things they put up aren't always what they seem..

Comment: Injecting content script to your own HTML file doesn't make much sense, I understand that you got confused by the snippets you have found. Please create a new question asking exactly what you are trying to build and stating what have you already written and I'm sure that someone will guide you in the right direction. Good luck!